# For $Y \sim Beta(n, 1)$, showing that $\frac{1}{n}log\int_{Y}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx$ converges in probability to $-\infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $Y \sim Beta(n, 1)$. I am interested in showing that

$$
\frac{1}{n}log\int_{Y}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx
$$

converges in probability to $-\infty$. (I was told in a book this is true)

My set-up is to show for $K>0$:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(\frac{1}{n}log\int_{Y}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx
<-K\right) = 1
$$

Now,

\begin{align}
P\left(\frac{1}{n}log\int_{Y}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx
<-K\right) &= P\left(\int_{Y}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx
<e^{-nK}\right)\\
&\leq P\left(\int_{Y}^1 x^{-1}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx
<e^{-nK}\right) \\
& \leq P\left(\int_{Y}^1 1\cdot dx
<e^{-nK}\right) \\
&= P\left(Y > 1-e^{-nK}\right) \\
&= 1-\left(1-e^{-nK}\right)^n
\end{align}

Above, my 2nd to 3rd inequality was obtained as $x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}$ is bounded below by $x^{-1}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}$, hence the terms inside the probability for $x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}$ is a subset of the terms inside the probability for $x^{-1}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}$.

The same for my 3rd to 4th inequality.

Applying the limit, the entire probability term goes to $0$. Hence:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left(\frac{1}{n}log\int_{Y}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx
<-K\right) = 0
$$

which is different from the result above. Does anyone know where I might have messed up? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is at 3rd to 4th inequality: $x^{-1}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}\to 0$ if $x\uparrow 1$ and can not therefore be greater than one..

Comment: Do you mean beta or gamma distribution? First displayed eqn in unmotivated. Was it given as part of the problem or is it your deduction from something unstated? Either way, if the integrand is supposed to be a density function, then it seems to be missing its constant.

Comment: @BruceET That was from the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{Y_n\}_{n\geq1}$ a sequence of random variables defined on the same probability space such that $Y_n\sim Beta(n,1)$ and $Y_n<Y_{n+1}$
we can see that that $g(u)=\frac{1}{n}log\int_{u}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx$ is a concave function, so by Jensen's inequality $E(g(Y_n))\leq g(E(Y_n))$ and $\{g(Y_n)\}_{n\geq1} $ is a decreasing sequence lower than zero, thus convergent. We have that
$$g(E(Y_n))=g\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{n}log\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx$$
which converges to $-\infty$ as $n\to \infty. $ and so does $g(Y_n)\to-\infty$, and since the sequence converges, it converges almost surely and probability.

The problem in your demonstration is, as stated by NCh, that $\begin{align}P\left(\int_{Y}^{1}x^{-1}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx<e^{-nK}\right) & \leq P\left(\int_{Y}^{1}1\cdot dx<e^{-nK}\right)\end{align}$ is not true.

Proof of $\frac{1}{n}log\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx\to-\infty$:

Using L'hôpital, if $\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^{1}x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx \to 0$
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{log\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^{1}x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx}{n} &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}e^{-\left(n+1\right)^{2}}/\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^{1}x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx}{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}e^{-\left(n+1\right)^{2}}}{\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^{1}x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx}\\
 &=e\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-2\left(n+1\right)e^{-\left(n+1\right)^{2}}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}e^{-(n+1)^{2}}}\\
 &=\lim_{n\to\infty}-2\left(n+1\right)\\
 &=-\infty\end{align*}
$$

Proof of $\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^{1}x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx \to 0$:

$\begin{align*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^{1}x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx &\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^{1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{-n}e^{-(\frac{n}{n+1}-1)^{-2}}dx\\
 &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{-n}e^{-(\frac{n}{n+1}-1)^{-2}}\left(1-\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\\
 &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}e^{-(n+1)^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
 &=0\end{align*}$

Proof of $g(u)=\frac{1}{n}log\int_{u}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx$ being concave:

let f,g be concave twice differentiable functions, if f is increasing then
$$f\left(h\left(u\right)\right)'' =f''\left(h\left(u\right)\right)h'\left(u\right)^{2}+f'\left(h\left(u\right)\right)h''\left(u\right)\leq0$$
if we apply that first to
$f(u)=u^{\frac{1}{n}}$, $h(u)=\int_{u}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx$

and then to
 $f(u)=log(u)$ and $h(u)=\left(\int_{u}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$

Proof of $h(u)=\int_{u}^1 x^{-n}e^{-(x-1)^{-2}}dx$ being concave:
$$
\begin{align*}
h'(u) & =u^{-n}e^{-(u-1)^{-2}}\\
h''(u) & =-nu^{-n}e^{-(u-1)^{-2}}-2u^{-n}e^{-(u-1)^{-2}}(1-u)^{-3}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: "which converges to $-\infty$ as $n\to \infty $" Why?

Comment: Now it is fixed